# GNU Make with patsubst: need two substitutions

Tags: makefile

I need to reference the stem twice in the replacement for a variable substitution:

`O23=$(OROOTS:%=$(ODIR)/overx-%2wk-%3wk.mlb)`

I need to perform two replacements with the same stem, but the substitution uses `patsubst` which only does the first.  How can we accomplish both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By kludgery:

```
O23=$(join $(OROOTS:%=$(ODIR)/overx-%2wk), $(OROOTS:%=-%3wk.mlb))
```

Comment: Short of using `$(shell)`, I can think of no better option. You win... this time.

Comment: This is inconvenient if you need your two substitutions to be separated by whitespace (as join removes it); you need to add some kind of unique delimiter and replace it back with whitespace afterwards....ewww

Comment: @Thomas: If there is whitespace between the substitution sites, the problem is *much* easier.

Comment: @Beta Indeed, I worked out a recursive join function with the word functions which works nicely.

Comment: @Thomas: a *recursive join function?* Why not just [`subst`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions)?

Answer (score 10):

In fact, Jack got it almost right -- `foreach` to the rescue!  We know the full stem anyway and stick it into a var, and `foreach` expands all occurrences of the var:

`O23 := $(foreach root,$(OROOTS),$(ODIR)/overx-$(root)2wk-$(root)3wk.mlb)`

I'll check Beta's anyway for the new perspective.

Answer (score 0):

By `$(shell)`:

```
O23 := $(foreach O,$(OROOTS),$(shell echo '$(O)' | awk '{print "overx-"$$0"2wk-"$$0"3wk.mlb"}'))
```

I think Beta's kludgery is probably better, since it doesn't have to fork out to `awk` for every word in `$(OROOTS)`.