# pathsubst with wildcard appearing 2 times

Tags: makefile

I want to replace a string like this
OntVeip -> ManagedObjects/OntVeip/OntVeipConfigDef.xml
so logically to me this is like :

```
% -> ManagedObjects/%/%ConfigDef.xml
```

If I try to do this with pathsubst, the % is only replaced once
ie

```
ManagedObjects := OntVeip OntMoca
XMLSOURCES := $(patsubst %,ManagedObjects/%/%ConfigDef.xml,$(ManagedObjects))
```

does not work as I was hoping for.

How can I achieve the result I am after ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liberally <s>stolen</s> adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5228778/657267)

```
XMLSOURCES := $(foreach obj,$(ManagedObjects),ManagedObjects/$(obj)/$(obj)ConfigDef.xml)
```